# Train Test Valid data sets... General question about fitting the models

Tags: random-forest, modeling

So I was given Xtrain, ytrain, Xtest, ytest, Xvalid, yvalid data for a HW assignment.  This assignment is for a Random Forest but I think my question can apply to any/most models.

So my understanding is that you use Xtrain and ytrain to fit the model such as (clf.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)) and this creates the model which can provide you a score and predictions for your training data

So when I move on to Test and Valid data sets, I only use ytest and yvalid to see how they predict and score.  My professor provided us with three X dataset (Xtrain, Xtest, Xvalid), but to me I only need the Xtrain to train the model initially and then test the model on the different y data sets.

If i did .fit() for each pair of X,y I would create/fit three different models from completely different data so the models are not comparable from my perspective.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Training step** :

Assuming your are using sklearn, the `clf.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)` method enables you to train your model (`clf`) to best fit the training data `Xtrain` and labels `ytrain`. At this stage, you can compute a score to evaluate your model on training data, as you said.

```
#train step
clf = your_classifier
clf.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

**Test step :**

Then, you have to use the test data `Xtest` to feed the prior trained model in order to generate new labels `ypred`.

```
#test step
ypred = clf.predict(Xtest)
```

Finally, you have to compare these generated labels `ypred` with the true labels `ytest` to provide a robust evaluation of the model performance on unknown data (data not used during training) with tools like confusion matrix, metrics...

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score

test_cm = confusion_matrix(ytest,ypred)
test_report = classification_report(ytest,ypred)
test_accuracy = accuracy_score(ytest, ypred)
```